# How to save and retrieve values from editText different for each listView row?

Tags: android, sql, android-listview, sharedpreferences

I have created a listView activity which opens dialog boxes on item click. In the dialog box, the users can enter different values, in an editText, which are saved in a textView, in the same list view item. That's working perfect, the problem is that if I close the application, when I open it again, the values saved, aren't there anymore. How to keep the value after closing the application?

I tried working with SharedPrefences, but the problem was that values are different for each row in the listView, so just sharing the TextView wasn't working. Then I tried something else, but for a week I got stuck into many NullPointerExceptins and I couldn't have done nothing so far on that way.

Here is my:

Adapter - **NoteAdapater.java:**

```
package com.cngcnasaud.orar;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NoteAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    String[] result;
    Context context;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    private Dialog dialog;


    public NoteAdapter(Note note, String[] prgmNameList, String[] saved) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        result = prgmNameList;
        context = note;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return result.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return result.length;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public class Holder {
        TextView tv;
        public TextView text;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        final Holder holder = new Holder();
        View rowView;
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.note_items, null);
        holder.tv = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.text = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        holder.tv.setText(result[position]);



        rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dialog = new Dialog(context);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
                dialog.setTitle("Materie:" + result[position]);

                final EditText txtMode = (EditText) dialog
                        .findViewById(R.id.dialog);
                Button btnSave = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.bsave);

                btnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        String data = txtMode.getText().toString();
                        holder.text.setText(data);



                        dialog.dismiss();
                        Log.d("data", data);
                    }
                });
                dialog.show();
            }

        });
        return rowView;
    }

}
```

And constructor - **Note.java**:

```
package com.cngcnasaud.orar;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Note extends Activity {

    public static final ListAdapter NoteAdapter = null;
    ListView lv;
    Context context;
    ArrayList<?> prgmName;


    public static String[] prgmNameList = { "Romana   - ", "Matematica   - ",
            "Lb. Engleza   - ", "Lb. Germana/Franceza - ", "Istorie   - ",
            "Geografie   - ", "Biologie   - ", "Fizica   - ", "Ed. Fizica   - " };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.note_listview);




        context = this;

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        lv.setAdapter(new NoteAdapter(this, prgmNameList, null));



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }



}
```

Comment: Create another class for save data, Save Your data in database class, and retrieve your values there and put in textview

Comment: It's looking so ambigous for me. Can you code an example for me please?

Comment: Check my answer and folow the tutorials also add there note example

Answer (score 0):

You are loosing the data because your data is static, you have define it in

```
prgmNameList = { "Romana   - ", "Matematica   - ",
        "Lb. Engleza   - ", "Lb. Germana/Franceza - ", "Istorie   - ",
        "Geografie   - ", "Biologie   - ", "Fizica   - ", "Ed. Fizica   - " };
```

Every time you close the app it will pick that data. In order to save the changes you need to implement a form of storage. Check the Android training page: [Saving Data](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html)

I think the best option is to make a database [Saving Data in SQL Databases](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html)

Comment: I'm sorry, but you didn't understand how my app worked. In each row form my listView I have one static text, defined as in your example, and one  dynamic textView, which is filled with values entered in the editText from the dialog box which was opened on item click from listView. I know how to save data, the only problem is that I can't save and retrieve the dynamic textView because if I do like that, then even if the user enter different value on other row, the values would be the same on each row of the listView. So, I want to avoid this problem. Thanks !

Comment: Ahh, sorry. I think now I understand. You are "saving" the data from the edittext in a TextView to show it in the ListView, buy you need some form of store the value the user input in somewhere else besides the textView.

Comment: Yes, something like that. And it's hard for to make this working, because I can't understand how to save it different for each row. Can you help me a little bit please? Thanks a lot !

Comment: @Andrei I am not an expert designing databases, but I would think a way would be have a database with a table where every row represent a row in your listview. For example. Row 0 in the list view need to be populate d with the date of the row 0 in the database. Sorry if I didn't explain it well, I am Spanish.

Comment: @Andrei, In this case, for simplicity, maybe it is better to simple store the values in a file. Where each row of the file also represents    a row in the ListView.

Comment: I understood your point, I know this, but I never worked with databases, so it's hard for me too to make it work, that's why I requested an example on my case. Anyway, thanks for trying.

Comment: @Andrei, You should check the Android page I told you. Here I left you  an example I wrote some time ago, it is in spanish, but the code would  help you. Scroll down to the class `DatabaseHelper` http://elbauldelprogramador.com/programacion-android-implementando-un_08/

Comment: @Andrei As your app only need store one value, your class will be more simple.

Answer (score 0):

Use  SQLite datbase for storing the data,It is static database kept all the values until uninstallation of the app.

Another way is use some online database using web-service.

For example [RESTFUL webservice](http://avilyne.com/?p=105)

Comment: I've read something about how SQL databases works, but I never worked with something like this, so I keept having some missing spaces about it. Can you code an example regarding to my codes please? Thanks !!!

Comment: i given a link wiith my answer,vist that.They explained very briefly .Using that link learn how to create webservice.